# How to check radio button on drop select

Tags: html, forms

I have a radio input that i would like selected when the user select from a drop down. The radio input has a name "rbutton" and id the same.
To clarify, I am using html forms.
Thanks.

Comment: Which language are you using. C#, VB??? You will have to provide a little more detail than that.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, i am using HTML forms

Comment: and could you *show your html*? What have you *tried*? What went wrong? How about a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you've *attempted* and are *working with* so far?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a small bit of javascript.

Here the `onclick` action on the drop down menu calls the `selectRadio` function which creates a checked radio button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectRadio(){
     document.getElementById('span1').innerHTML = '<input type="radio" checked="true"/>';
}
</script>
<form>
    <p><span id='span1'><input type="radio"/></span> Radio Button</p> 
    <p>Choose option:</p>
    <select onclick='selectRadio()'/>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```